# MySQL Stored Procedures i

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, sql-update

I am a Newbee using MySQL Workbench.   I have a table Called requests.  It has  a column called STATUS and another called EXPIREDDATE. I want to create a Stored procedure that Inputs the text "Exipred" into the column STATUS if the date in EXPIREDDATE exceeds Todays date. The begining of the code is below.  Thanks.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Add Expired` ( IF expireddate => todays date THEN status = "expired")
BEGIN

END
```

Comment: Why do you even need to have a column? Whenever you run a query on the field you can use IF (ExpiryDate <= currentDate) condition to get the term "Expired" in your recordset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Inputs the text "Expired" in to a column `A` if the date in column `B` exceeds Todays date

You are describing an `update` statement with filtering:

```
update mytable set a = 'expired' where b > current_date
```

You can easily turn this to a stored procedure - although it wouldn't be very helpful (you can just run the query).

Comment: Ah I see thanks a bunch!  I just updated my Post can you see how I did the stored procedure.  Is the a way I can do it like that  thanks

Comment: @kumbi: you don't need a stored procedure for that. Just use the `update` query as it is.